# Cannot access brew-installed Jenkins in VirtualBox

Tags: macos, jenkins, virtualbox

I installed the Jenkins through `brew install jenkins-lts` in macOS.

The macOS is running as VirtualBox VM instance on Windows Host.

On VirtualBox host Windows, I cannot access Jenkins through `http://localhost:8080` or `http://10.0.2.15:8080` from browser. (`10.0.2.15` is my guest VM macOS's IP address)

What I've setup

- Jenkins-lts service is started. macOS safari can access through `http://localhost:8080`
- VirtualBox port forwarding is set, TCP/HOST: `0.0.0.0:8080` /GUEST: `10.0.2.15:8080`
- By the same port forwarding setup for `SSH` HOST: `0.0.0.0:22` /GUEST: `10.0.2.15:22`, I can successfully connect to `SSH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the default config file `/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.x.x/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`. `brew-installed` Jenkins's default listening address is `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`. This causes Jenkins's web server only listen request from localhost instead of any network adapter.

Steps

1. Edit config file, `vi /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.x.x/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`
2. Find the row `<string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>` and change to `<string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>`
3. Restart Jenkins, `brew services restart jenkins-lts`

References

1. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/, denoted httpListenAddress
2. https://medium.com/@vishnuteja/install-jenkins-as-a-service-on-macos-and-change-port-number-9aa097e5cfbf, denoted where brew-install Jenkins's config file.